# NullReferenceException in IIS but not in VS 2015

Tags: iis, nullreferenceexception

I've been working on a MVC with Extjs 6 which works perfectly when I run it on visual studio 2015, however when i deploy it to IIS 8.5  in Windows 2012 R2, i get a null reference exception. The error occurs immediately, as soon, after login and when the page tries to load.
Info:
 Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.6.1055.0
assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0
in Windows 2012 R2
IIS:8.5

Thank you.

> [NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.]
>      HiplotTM.Controllers.HomeController.Login(Usuarios objUsuario) +739
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +138
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +228
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +71
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

Comment: The problem according to my point of view is , that the dataContext  does not instantiate: HiplotTMdbConexion dataContext = new HiplotTMdbConexion when the project is deployed in the IIS. some ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason:

> 1. Check your code.
> 2. Check Web.config file for null reference exception.